# What happens when no thread is free in the thread pool and we submit a task to the pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Will the thread creating method wait for a thread to get free?
can I reduce the number of threads generated using thread pooling?

Comment: This is not what happens; internally, a thread pool maintains a queue of `Callable`s, and dequeues one `Callable` to assign to a thread when one is "free to use".

Comment: Are you talking about [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) or something more general?

Answer (score 3):

If you use a cached thread pool, the pool will create more threads. However this will only be the maximum needed at any one time and might be far less than the number of tasks you submit.

If you use a fixed size thread pool, it will create a fixed number of threads regardless of whether you give it any tasks, or if you give it more tasks than it can do.  It will queue any tasks which are waiting.

> Will the thread creating method wait for a thread to get free?

While you could create a queue which did this, this is not the default behaviour. A more common solution is to make the caller execute the task if this is required.

> can I reduce the number of threads generated using thread pooling?

Thread pooling is likely to produce far less threads than tasks esp if you limit the number of threads.

Answer (score 1):

> Will the thread creating method wait for a thread to get free?

That contradicts with your title. You'd normally submit a task and the pool would pass that task to a worker thread when one is available. So you'd not *create* a thread but *submit* a task. Whether you wait for the task to be executed or just trigger asynchronous execution (which in most cases would be the default) depends on your system and requirements.

> Can I reduce the number of threads generated using thread pooling?

Thread pooling is often used to reduce the number of threads created, i.e. instead of having a thread per task you have a defined (maximum) number of worker threads and thus if `#tasks > max threads in pool` you'll reduce the number of threads needed.

Answer (score 0):

From the ThreadPoolExecutor documentation:

> A ThreadPoolExecutor will automatically adjust the pool size (see
>   getPoolSize()) according to the bounds set by corePoolSize (see
>   getCorePoolSize()) and maximumPoolSize (see getMaximumPoolSize()).
>   When a new task is submitted in method execute(java.lang.Runnable),
>   and fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is
>   created to handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle.
>   If there are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize
>   threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is
>   full. By setting corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize the same, you create
>   a fixed-size thread pool. By setting maximumPoolSize to an essentially
>   unbounded value such as Integer.MAX_VALUE, you allow the pool to
>   accommodate an arbitrary number of concurrent tasks. Most typically,
>   core and maximum pool sizes are set only upon construction, but they
>   may also be changed dynamically using setCorePoolSize(int) and
>   setMaximumPoolSize(int).

Basically, you can set two sizes: the 'core' size and the 'max' size. When tasks are submitted, if there are fewer than 'core' threads, a new thread will be created to execute that task. If there are greater than 'core' threads, one of the current threads will be used to execute tasks, unless all current threads are busy. If all current threads are busy, more threads will be created up to 'max' size. Once 'max' number of threads are reached, no more will be created, and new tasks will be queued until a thread is available to run them.

In the general case, there is no 'right' way that thread pools work. Any given implementation could be used: a fixed size thread pool that always has X threads, or a thread pool that always grows up to a maximum limit, etc.

Comment: Just one thing wrong in your answer: when all core threads are busy the incomming task will be put in the queue and if the queue is full then a new thread will be created up to maxPoolSize.

Answer (score 0):

`ThreadPoolExecutor's` submitted  method throws `RejectedExecutionException` if the task cannot be scheduled for execution.